# want figures references to print as 1(a), 1(b) istead of 1a,1b

Tags: elsarticle

i am using the elsarticle class with following packages

```
%\documentclass[3p,times,procedia,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\documentclass[preprint,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{ecrc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[caption]{subfig}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multicol}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\include{pythonlisting}
```

and i am using the subfigure package

[image: reference image]

and i want to print the references as 1(a), 1(b) instead of 1a,1b as we can see in the image i uploaded

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: For document submission to a journal, the usual advice is to change only as much as you absolutely have to. If the journal have picked a style, it's normally best to stick with it. As such, I'd be very wary of modifying cross-refs at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the way `subcaption` typesets the label and redefine `\thesubfigure` to have parentheses around the letter.

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
abc
\caption{A}\label{sf:a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{5cm}
def
\caption{B}\label{sf:b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{C}\label{f:c}
\end{figure}

\ref{sf:a} and \ref{sf:b}
\end{document}
```

[image]